# If my characters can control electrons could they use this as a means to attract and repel objects?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

Could they use their abilities to change an objects electromagnetic fields to work in their favour.
I want my magic system to be explained as the story progresses. I’m thinking this could be a way to explain telekinesis? If this sounds plausible would they be limited by their size i.e. only able to manipulate objects a fraction of their size?

Comment: With the small problems that adding of removing significant numbers of electrons to or from an object will drastically change its chemistry... with immediate and rather spectacular results.

Comment: Just what, exactly, can they do to electrons, specifically?  @AlexP mentioned adding and removing, is that what you mean?  or can they do more than that? or something else entirely, like shift all the electrons to one side or another of an atom or molecule and hold it there? etc.

Answer (score 4):

### the Basics

Short answer yes.

https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/magnetism-and-magnetic-fields/

Well we know from Amperes law the relation between a magnetic field and the current pathing through the surface of that path. In short you can create a magnetic field with a current of electrons moving in a circle.

In a second step you can use the Lorentz law to induce an internal current in an object while creating a magnetic field through more electrons moving outside the object to create that field. This will get your object moving.

There are however drawbacks with this

1. Not all objects are very good conductors (having many free electrons) so creating a current in them will likely damage them
2. The magnetic fields you will have to create are somewhat complex depending on the situation, yet you have to go through electrons to create your magnetic fields

### diamagnetic levitation

That said if your outer magnetic fields are strong enough and have the right form you can repel diamagnetic objects. Even biological ones.

https://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic-levitation/

### paramagnetic/ferromagnetic levitation

Will require less strong fields to get done. The principle is the same as with diamagnetic materials though.

### creating currents magically

Is dangerous ... your power is more of the I can electrocute you with my mind kind, rather than I can levitate you.

Also as all materials will have some sort of resistance to you moving your electrons through is bound to cost you energy as the perpetrator.

Limitations of your power very much depend on the energy you can exert and what your powers can move. 
A lot of what I said becomes void when you can move electrons trapped even in the potential of atoms. I would not suggest this however but only limit this to those already free roaming electrons.

As you are moving millions of electrons simultaneously you will have to have an impressive brain capability.

### conclusion

You are

1. A super computer moving single electrons to your whim
2. You have to eat a lot to conserve the energy
3. You are close to god hood and Maxwell wants to have a word with you!

Comment: Can't you just pull/push all electrons inside of an object and because of the charge all the nucleus will move with it?

Comment: Good question! But I did assume here that you only have control over those electrons that are already free and not caught by the potential well of an atom. So there would be no direct control of the electron hull of an atom. But yes it seems plausible that this might work as well. However I’m not sure how well this manipulation would work without breaking them out of the atomic well. There is not enough information on the rules it works by.

Comment: I mean you would have to be incredible precise and careful with your movements as even in an conductor the speed at which individual electrons move is slow. So not to literally rip apart the atoms you would need to be even slower.

Comment: Sure, but maybe it works more like having a though of electrical potential without controlling them directly? Besides if you have control of charge ..why only electrons to begin with?